# socket.io with Node.js and React.js UI does not update when I open multiple tabs or another tab in a different browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am developing a small application in Node.js and React.js I am using sockets for real-time communication in order to update a single value after 10 seconds. The problem is that when I open a new tab in the same browser or when I hit the same URL with the different browser, previously opened tab does not update. I am unable to figure this out why the previously opened tab freezes and the value does not update in it but the value updates in the real time in only newly opened tab. I have attached my code.

**Node.js code**

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const cors = require('cors')

const port = 8080;

const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ response: "I am alive" }).status(200);
});

const app = express();
app.use(router);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server, {
  transports:['polling'],
  cors:{
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  }
});

app.use(cors())

let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => generateValue(socket), 10000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

const generateValue= socket => {
  var min = 100;
  var max = 3000;
  const Value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  socket.emit("generateValue", Value);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**React.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
// import logo from './logo.svg';
// import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Value: 0,
      endpoint: "http://localhost:8080"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.Value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    socket.on("generateValue", data => this.setState({ Value: data }));
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify this variable. So it can save interval individually, per connection.

```js
let interval;
```

For example:

```js
let intervalsBySocketId = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const socketId = socket.id;

  // these lines is not needed
  // if (interval) {
  //  clearInterval(interval);
  //}
  intervalsBySocketId[socketId] = setInterval(() => generateValue(socket), 10000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    clearInterval(intervalsBySocketId[socketId]);
    delete intervalsBySocketId[socketId];
  });
});
```